# Popen() doesn't redirect the stdout to a file

Tags: python, c, subprocess, popen, python-c-api

I have a python program that calls a subprocess using Popen(). **This python program is called from a C program, using the Python/C API**.
Everything works fine except for the fact that the subprocess doesn't redirect the output to a file. If I use just the Python program, it works as it's supposed to do. If I call the same program from C, it doesn't.

Any clue?

```
fout = open('fout.txt','w+')
self.process = Popen(starting_cmd,stdout=fout)
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] including a minimal C and python program

Answer (score 1):

With this minimum information I can't help you a lot but I'll suggest you do something like this :

```py
with open("fout.txt","a") as out:
    subprocess.Popen("starting_cmd",stdout=out)
```

- The process don't need to read info so we don't need to open the file in reading mode (and it's a best practice to restrain the access to a file to only what's necessary). You could therefore replace `w+` with just `w` or `a` (to append `fout.txt`).
- The `with` is for context managing to be sure the file is closed when `out` goes out of scope, which can potentially help to make the result visible in the file.

Here's a working example (in python3) :

```py
import subprocess
with open("fout.txt", "a") as out:
    subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=out)
```